# Unable to activate a conda environment

Tags: jupyter, virtualenv, conda

I have installed miniconda.
I am running the command on powershell(VSCode).

I am unable to activate my conda env as shown below:

[image]

Potential reasons could be the space in the user name:

[image]

What do you guys suggest?

I was expecting to activate my env.

Answer (score 0):

Can you run `conda init` once. 
Because `(base)` env should come first.

Comment: thanks for your response. it made me aware that I didn't have jupyter installed.